# Radius of convergence of series 3

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am stuck in the following excercise: Determine the radius of convergence of the following series:
$$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1+k)^{ak}}{(k!)^3}x^k$$
for $a>0$ as a function of $a$.

And I am allowed to use the result: $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n=e^x(1+O(n^{-1}))$ as $n\to\infty$

any help appreciated

Comment: What have you tried? Have you attempted to use any convergence tests? For me, there's two particular convergence tests that scream to me whenever I see factorials...

Comment: Also, I believe your "result" that you are allowed to use is slightly faulty. The left hand side has no $x$'s, and the right hand side does...

Comment: I think the left hand side has an ‘x’ and the right hand side too.

Comment: At the time of my comment, the [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2581283/1) indicates there was no $x$ on the LHS. Indeed, [another user](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2581283/2) had to come in and edit it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle a_k=\frac{\left(1+k\right)^{ak}}{\left(k!\right)^3}$.
The sequence is strictly positive and
$$
\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac{\left(2+k\right)^{a\left(k+1\right)}}{\left(k+1\right)!^3}\frac{\left(k!\right)^3}{\left(1+k\right)^{ak}}=\left(\frac{2+k}{1+k}\right)^{ak}\frac{\left(2+k\right)^{a}}{\left(k+1\right)^3}=\left(1+\frac{1}{1+k}\right)^{ak}\frac{\left(2+k\right)^{a}}{\left(k+1\right)^3}
$$
Here comes your formula
$$
\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=e^{a\frac{k}{k+1}+o\left(1\right)}\frac{\left(2+k\right)^{a}}{\left(k+1\right)^3}\underset{k \rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\frac{\left(e\left(2+k\right)\right)^{a}}{k^3}\underset{k \rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}e^{a}k^{a-3}
$$
 if $a=3$ the radius is $R=e^{-3}$.

if $a>3$ the radius is $R=0$.

if $a<3$ the radius is $R=+\infty$.

I hope it's ok now, sorry